# Java regex for a method signature with a Collection<GenericType> return type

Tags: java, regex, generics

What would be the Java regular expression to match a Java method return type such as the following:

```
ArrayList<CodeObject>
```

Comment: It's useful when asking a regexp question to give several example inputs of what would match and what wouldn't match..

Comment: This is either a trivial question of you aren't providing anywhere near all the details of what you want to do. Do you really just want a boolean result, or do you want to disassemble it? What about a<b<c, d<e>>>.

Comment: My apologies, I just want a boolean result. I don't need to disassemble it. I am really just concerned about a<b> for now, however un-robust that sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the existence of:

```
 Map<List<String>, Map<List<String>, Collection<Integer>>>
```

just for starters, I'm going to claim that this is a bad job for a regexp. Regexps are not good at matching nested items. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/131433) for the deleterious effects on mental health of trying.

For the simple case I think the following would serve.

```
 \p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*<\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*>
```